# Are finitely generated modules over a commutative local ring cancellative?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M,N,P$ be finitely generated modules over a (Notherian) local ring $R$. If $M \oplus N \cong M \oplus P$, do we have $N \cong P$ ?
If not, what if we further assume that $M \cong R^n$ for some positive integer $n$, or even $M=R$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true. See Proposition 1 [in this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102946603) which contains many other interesting results on decompositions of modules over local rings.

Update: Also see [this paper of T.Y. Lam](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263872032_A_crash_course_on_stable_range_cancellation_substitution_and_exchange) for a more recent reference (thanks to rschwieb for suggesting this).

Comment: Good reference, thanks.

Comment: @sagnikchakraborty also, much more recently: “A crash course on stable range and cancellation” by T.Y. Lam.  (You can steal this citation you add to your solution, metal!)

Comment: @rschwieb Sure thing, thanks for suggesting it!

Comment: Thanks, to both of you.